# How to set the CSS content property with a Google Material Icon?

Tags: css, material-design, google-material-icons, contentproperty

How can I insert the Google Material Icon "chevron icon right" (https://design.google.com/icons/#ic_chevron_right) in the following CSS content property:

```
.bullet li a:before {
    content: "";
}
```

Comment: TLDR they are called "Code point" on the icons directory, e.g. for the Arrow Upward icon the Code point content is `e5d8` which you would then reference in your CSS as `content: "\e5d8";` https://fonts.google.com/icons?icon.query=arrow

Answer (score 69, accepted):

**Update on 2018**

Google removed the codes which were displayed earlier for IE9 and below. To get the codes visit the codepoints file in the GitHub repository.

Link to codepoints in GitHub repository: https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/blob/master/font/MaterialIcons-Regular.codepoints

---

Step 1: Include the Material Icons Stylesheet.

`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">`

Step 2 :

CSS Code:

```
.bullet li a:before {
    font-family: "Material Icons";
    content: "\e5cc";
}
```

**Explanation**: The value `e5cc` is the code which you see for the chevron.

[image]

Comment: For modern browsers supporting the CSS feature [`font-feature-settings`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-feature-settings) you can simply use the icon's name instead of the code point: `.bullet li a:before { font-family: "Material Icons"; content: "chevron_right" }`

Answer (score 16):

```css
::before {
    font-family: 'Material Icons';
    content: "\E87C";
}

::after {
    font-family: 'Material Icons';
    content: "face";
}
```

http://codepen.io/estelle/pen/MwvOjd

Comment: Didn't realize you could refer to the icon directly by name in the `content` prop - neat tip!

Answer (score 7):

**Update for 2022**

Using the new Material Symbols Outlined

```
.selector::before {
    font-family: "Material Symbols Outlined";
    content: "\e5cc";
}
```

[Reference here](https://fonts.google.com/icons?icon.query=chevron%20right)

Answer (score 6):

Try this.

```
.bullet li a:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f054";
}
```

You can refer [here for content values](http://astronautweb.co/snippet/font-awesome/)

Comment: remember set font-family too :P

Comment: okay... did you include required CSS , fonts and apis for Google material design?

Comment: I have included MDL

Answer (score 2):

If you already included the minified CSS from [materialdesignicons.com](http://materialdesignicons.com/) then just use the Material Design Icons font family instead:

```
::after {
    font-family: 'Material Design Icons';
    content: "\f054";
}
```

There is also a convenient [Cheat Sheet](https://cdn.materialdesignicons.com/3.8.95/) available.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this for rtl mode:

```
.bullet li a:before {content: '\E5CB';}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update on Jun 2021**

The code points of Material Icons are in the Google Fonts webpage, in the section of Material Icons.

Step 1: Include the Material Icons Stylesheet.

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

Step 2: CSS Code.

```
::after {
    font-family: 'Material Icons';
    content: "/e5cc";
}
```

**Explanation:** The value `e5cc` is the code which you see for the chevron in the next link and image.

https://fonts.google.com/icons?selected=Material+Icons&icon.query=chevron

[How to get the content code of chevron icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gncy2.jpg)